# MySQL select random records with limit

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query for selecting random records with a limit of 6.

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . $this->table . "` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT " . $limit);
```

If I set the limit to 6, it will sometimes only show 4 records, sometimes 5.
How can I make it always show 6?
I have more than 6 records in the database.

I looked at some questions around this here but couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: Mmm... I am not able to [reproduce your issue](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rnuP33nHKC6Ex967czuSmi/0).

Comment: @GMB perfect reason to vote to close as non-reproducible...

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in your application layer? Can you share more of the PHP code?

Comment: Where does limit come from? It is the only place where there can be an issue

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` is also a fantastic way to exponentially tank your DB performance as your data set grows.

Comment: @Nick limit is just a variable passed in.. an integer like 6 for example

Comment: @devManMan understand. But there is no problem with the code you have posted, so for anyone to help you with the problem you will need to post more of your PHP code.

Comment: And the venerable [ORDER BY RAND()](https://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/)

Comment: there is no issue with the SQL query posted

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . $this->table . "` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT $limit " );
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score -2):

Try with :
SELECT RAND(6)

$query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . $this->table . "` ORDER BY RAND(6) LIMIT " . $limit);

Comment: The parameter to `RAND` merely changes the seed from which the random numbers are generaed and would have no effect on the result of the query.